# jQuery Ajax xBrowser for JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have some code that uses jQuery to make an AJAX call to a non-local server for 'supposed' JSON data. However, I have no way of knowing what the data yet contains, as I am receiving a bad return from the `$.parseJSON(varjson)` method.

The HTTP request in my web console indicates the response text is 307 characters long, so is there a way for me to simply check what's in the response?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#button").click(function(){                
        var url = "http://developer.pw-hq.com/api/session";

        var success = function(data){
        alert('in function');
            var html = [];
            /* parse JSON */
            //data = $.parseJSON(data);
            /* loop through array */
            alert(data);
            $.each(data, function(index, d){            
                html.push(
                          "Device Secret : ", d.deviceSecret, ", ",
                          "Name : ", d.name, ", ",
                          "ID : ", d.id, ", ",
                          "Role : ", d.role, ", ",
                          "Trust Level : ", d.trustLevel, ", ",
                          "E-Mail : ", d.email, ", ",
                          "Timezone : ", d.timezone, ", ")
            });
            alert(html);
            console.log(data);
            $("#return").html(html.join('')).css("background-color", "orange");
        };

        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',    
          url: url,
          data:{email:"applicant@pw.me.as-a.com", password:"assessmyskillz", deviceId:""},
          dataType: "application/json",
          crossDomain: true,          
          cache:false, 
          success: success,
          error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
          alert(xhr.status);
          alert(thrownError);
          }
        });
    });
});
```

Feel free to attempt a solution. The credentials are legitimate. For potential work :-p

Comment: To get a meaningful answer please read the FAQ with instructions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and a personal favorite of mine: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried

Comment: Firebug will show you.  Also the JavaScript Console in Chrome

Comment: `console.log(varjson)`. When you say "non-local server" do you mean you're doing a JSONP call to a different domain?

Comment: Most likely you are already getting JSON back and jQuery is parsing it automatically making your `$.parseJSON` call redundant and incorrect

Comment: Which console are you using? If you use firebug or chrome you can look for the request on the network tabs and then look at the response header. If you run IE download http://fiddler2.com/, to view the packets. Then once you have the response data you can use http://jsonlint.com/ you can verify if the json is correct.

Comment: Dont parse the response as json - just print it in the console plainly

Comment: In the firebug console, the http response header indicates a content length of 307 but the response has nothing in it. 

My advice, never do some stupid test for a job. Thanks guys all excellent suggestions  I tried most of them.

Comment: The issue was with the response content, ill transmitted with a faulty header. I was using the default web console in FF and needed to Firebug add-on to determine this. Good work fellas.